# Why is my select criteria not allowing me to append HTML "td" attributes to a D3 generated HTML Table?

Tags: d3.js, html-table

I'm trying to construct a sortable table using D3.  In the debugger, I can watch the DOM objects be constructed, right down to the table body records ().  However, when I attempt to use a for loop to append table data elements () to each table record, nothing is appending.  I can't tell if the problem is my select approach, the syntax for the append, or the for look.

Any thoughts?

The original code is at: http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/8203388

My code is:

```
//THIS IS THE LAST THING THAT SEEMS TO WORK FINE...

    // Select the HTML tbody element and append an HTML tr element to create body records
    var densityBody = d3.selectAll("#density_body").selectAll("tbody.tr")
      .data(totalsArray)
      .enter()
      .append("tr")
        .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "density_body_record-" + i; })
        .on("mouseover", bodyRecordMouseOver)
        .on("mouseout", bodyRecordMouseOut);

// THINGS START TO BREAK INSIDE THIS FOR LOOP...

    for(var z = 0; z < totalsArray.length; z++){
      // Select the HTML tr elements in the tbody and append HTML td elements
      var dataSelectString = "#density_body_record-" + z;
      var densityBodyDataRecords = d3.selectAll(dataSelectString).selectAll("tr.td") // HERE!!!
        .data(totalsArray[z])
        .enter()
        .append("td")
          // Append text to each column
          .text(function(d) { return d; 

          });
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you're using an invalid selector: `"tr.td"` will select table row (`<tr>`) elements that have a *class* of `"td"`.  What you intended was `"tr > td"`, or table data (`<td>`) elements that are direct children of table row elements.  Same problem in the first section -- you're adding rows to a selection that D3 thinks is table body elements.

Then, as @Barnab said, there is the the fact that you're joining one object (containing the whole row's data) to your selection, not an array of individual data elements.  His suggestion works, but at the expense of hard-coding in all the column names in an order that isn't accessible outside that one line of code.  If you add data categories or delete them, you have to go monkeying around with this code and with any code for creating column header labels.

One alternative would be to use the [`d3.entries(object)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#associative-arrays) method, which will return an array, where each element of the array is an object representing a key and value pair from the original object.  However, the method doesn't guarantee the order that the key-value pairs will appear in the array it creates, so you would have to sort the array returned by `d3.entries()` based on the key value and a custom sort function.

Another approach is to define the order of columns as it's own array (possibly read in or calculated from the data source), and then use that to create the array of table-cell data objects from the row data objects.

I've got an example at the end, but first you'll have to read up on using [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) for table rows and then table cells, as a much more elegant alternative to using a `for` loop to scan through the rows.

The trick is how to go from having one data object for the entire row to having an array of objects for each column, when you want those data objects to be based on both the row data *and* the column data array.

I created this example for someone else, but it shows how to use a customizable function to combine row and column data with nested selections:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/un58H/
([The source of the function I was trying to explain.](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/20))

Except in your case, you wouldn't want to create a new object from the row and column data, but to use the column data to access the associated value from the row data object.  Like this:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/un58H/2/

Note a few other things about the fiddle:

- by declaring an array of column keys, you can use that array as the data to populate the column headers;
- the order in which data is declared in the object is irrelevant; the final order is determined by the column names array;
- if some rows don't have values for a particular column, you can leave them out of the data object and just check for null values when using the data object in each cell.

Comment: Great answer that gives you big picture and helps navigate through the maze of objects and table rows, columns, and cells.

Comment: Thanks Amelia.  Quick question.  You mentioned that my selection was wrong because "tr.td" selects all table records and elements that have a "class" value of "td".  May I ask what the right syntax is to select all table data <td> elements within a table record <tr>?  -- thanks.

Comment: `"tr > td"` for direct children, `"tr td"` for all descendents.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Comment: I should add a warning that "tr > td" finds *all* table data elements that have a table row as a parent, regardless of whether that table row is part of your current selection; this can be an issue if you have nested tables (or nested lists, nested groups, etc.)  In that case, you'd need classes as well to distinguish between your nesting levels.  See [this discussion](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/1618#issuecomment-28076822) on the d3 github.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for the second `.data` call :

```
.data([totalsArray[z].Name, totalsArray[z].Relationships, totalsArray[z].Percentage, totalsArray[z].Density])
```

With your code totalsArray[z] is an object and I don't see how D3 can iterate over its attributes. In my implementation the `return d` part in `.text` will iterate over the array passed in `.data`.